How can I execute js when loading a sub route on a static build in Sveltekit
I never noticed this before, but I've encountered a weird issue in my Sveltekit application. To put it simply, I have a ("/map") sub route that when refreshed/loaded directly as the sub route won't execute any JS, I noticed this is the general case for all sub routes. when loading a sub route, no matter which one ("/about"), ("/map") it renders all the HTML and CSS perfectly but won't execute any JS, UNLESS you load the root first ("/") and navigate via links or goTo to a sub route ("/map").
I'm using a static adapter, but this also happens with the adapter-auto. There is no issue in the dev environment, when running

npm run dev

but when testing the production build

npm run build

and running

npm run preview

the issue arises.
I want people to be able to load ("https://www.example.com/map") directly instead of having to go to ("https://www.example.com/") first and route from there just so that Sveltekit can execute the JS hence load the imports and other necesseties for the map to properly function and laod.

Your question is unclear:  It needs to specify which JS is not executing.  Where is this JS that you need that doesn't execute?

Any JS code inside the 
I solved this by creating a new layout in my "routes" folder, so basically this is how my routes folder looks like:
.
└── routes/
    ├── (map)/map
    │   ├── +layout.svelte
    │   ├── +page.svelte
    │   └── +page.ts
    ├── about/
    │   ├── +page.svelte
    │   └── +page.ts
    ├── +layout.svelte
    ├── +page.svelte
    └── +page.ts

This way any sub folder created as a new layout like (main) will be treated as a root folder and execute even JS on a refresh or load.

What you are experiencing is SSR:  Server-Side Rendering.  It is not that it doesn't run, it runs in the server side, not the browser side.
SSR in Sveltekit runs the code in the <script> tags in the NodeJS server, and then simply transmit the resulting HTML.  Then, during hydration, the Svelte runtime executes effects, transitions, etc.

I know what SSR and CSR are. I don't think that this is the issue here. I'm using a static build and have set everything to CSR. The main problem here is that without loading the root ("/") route first, it won't execute any JS. I already posted a solution to this problem. To really understand this. Just run a the prebuilt Sveltekit app and add some JS to the about page then build the app and run npm run preview, load http://localhost:4173/about and you will see the that any logs or any other is not executed, unless you load http://localhost:4173 first and then route to the /about page
